# Vector of linked lists not working properly

Tags: c, linked-list, grammar

I'm very beginner at C programming, and I'm trying to create an algorithm to find *first* and *follow* sets of a given grammar that will be in a .txt file.

The input grammar looks like this:

```
S-abA|e|bhG|AKX
A-Kb|d
K-j|c|e
X-p
```

So far I'm just trying to define the structures that I'm gonna use to find those sets (and that's what I'm having trouble with).

I'm using a vector of lists in which each list will contain the RHS values of my grammar, and each position in the vector (defined by the number of rules or lines in the input file) will be a pointer to a list.
The function below compiles and *almost* works. The productions are being read correctly and the variable "producao" is working fine, I've tried printing it out and it is getting each value correctly, but when I add those values to the list what I end up with when I print the whole list is:
[image]

And what I should have is:
[image]

The function that I'm having trouble with is posted below:

```
criaListaRegras()
{
    lista *regras;
    regras = cria_lista(); // initialize list pointing to null
    lista **vetor; // declare the vector of list pointers
    vetor = malloc(sizeof(lista)*numLinhas);

    int i = 0;
    int numLinha = 0;
    char producao[10]; // Each production in the RHS will have at most 9 characters and will be added to this variable, one at a time.
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada = fopen("entrada.txt", "r"); // input file
    fseek(entrada, 2, SEEK_SET); // seek to RHS of the rule. (S-ab|AbB), makes fp go to 'a'.
    char linha; // Will be used to parse the input

    while ((linha = getc(entrada)) != EOF){
        if (linha == '\n'){ // checks if a rule has ended, so that we add end of string to production and append that into the list.
            producao[i] = '\0';
            inserir(regras, producao); // append production (producao) into the list (regras).
            imprimir(regras); // should print all values inside "regras" but only print the last value added * "number of productions found so far".
            vetor[numLinha] = regras; // should assign a list into its position in the pre-defined vector of lists at position "numLinha".
            i = 0; // resets string position counter to 0 so we can reuse it for next production.
            numLinha++; // increment line/rule counter.
            fseek(entrada, 2, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        if (linha == '|'){ // our production delim is '|', so if we find it, means a production has ended and we should add it into the list.
            producao[i] = '\0';
            inserir(regras, producao);
            i = 0;
        }
        if(linha != '|' && linha != '\n'){ // this means the current char (linha) is part of some RHS production, so we should concatenate it into the variable producao on position 'i' and increment 'i'.
            producao[i] = linha;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The other functions used in *criaListaRegras()* are working fine for test values and can be found below:

```
lista *cria_lista()
{
    lista *novo = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    novo->next = NULL;
    return novo;
}

void imprimir(lista *original)
{
    lista * aux = original->next;

    while(aux!= NULL){
        printf("%s\n", aux->nome);
        aux=aux->next;
    }
}

void inserir(lista *original, char *nome)
{
    lista *base = original;
    lista *aux = original->next;
    lista *novo;

    while(aux!= NULL){
        aux=aux->next;
        base=base->next;
    }

    novo=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    novo->nome = nome;
    novo->next = aux;
    base->next = novo;
}
```

I'll be glad if someone can point me what I'm doing wrong there.

Comment: Note: `char linha;` --> `int linha; (since you are using `while ((linha = getc(entrada)) != EOF ) {` )

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the provides source code and building a complete sample using `criaListaRegras()` function, I have detected multiple errors and a potential one able to create the observed output.

**Hypothesis 1** - how is declared the structure `lista`.

When parsing the source code, `lista` has 2 attributes `next` (used for the linked-list mechanism) and `nome` to store loaded "producao" (char producao[10];).

```
typedef struct slista {
    char *nome; // or char nome[10];
    struct slista *next;
} lista;
```

**Problem 1** - attached to that `lista` structure, the function `inserir()` is not storing the content of the `char *nome` parameter but only the pointer.

```
novo=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
novo->nome = nome; // ERROR storing the pointer
novo->next = aux;
base->next = novo;
```

By storing the pointer of the `char *nome` parameter (which is the pointer of the local variable `char producao[10];`), each node `lista` will have the pointer value and when using `imprimir()`, the `aux->nome` will point to the last entry (for `"S-abA|e|bhG|AKX"`, it is `"AKX"`, ...).

**Solution 1.1** - if the attribute of `lista` is declared as `char *nome;`, it is needed to allocate the string and copy the content.

> The easiest solution is to use `strdup()` able to allocate and copy a
>   string.

```
novo=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
novo->nome = strdup(nome); // allocate and copy
novo->next = aux;
base->next = novo;
```

**Solution 1.2** - if the attribute of `lista` is declared as `char nome[10];`, it is needed to only copy the string.

> The input (from `char producao[10];`) is limited to (10-1) `char` and
>   can be copied easily with the function `strcpy()`.

```
novo=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
strcpy(novo->nome,nome); // copy from nome to novo->nome
novo->next = aux;
base->next = novo;
```

**Other detected problems:**

**1-** Allocate a `vetor` of `lista`.

> The variable`lista **vetor;` is an array of `lista *` instead of
>   `lista`.

```
lista **vetor; // declare the vector of list pointers
vetor = (lista **)malloc(sizeof(lista *)*numLinhas);
```

Instead of

```
lista **vetor; // declare the vector of list pointers
vetor = (lista **)malloc(sizeof(lista)*numLinhas);
```

**2-** Check the `FILE *entrada;` value after using `fopen()` and before reading data.

**3-** After storing a complete `lista *regras` (`vetor[numLinha] = regras;`) in the `vetor`, you need to create a new one.

> Call again `regras = cria_lista();`

```
imprimir(regras); // should print all values inside "regras" but only print the last value added * "number of productions found so far".
vetor[numLinha] = regras; // should assign a list into its position in the pre-defined vector of lists at position "numLinha".
i = 0; // resets string position counter to 0 so we can reuse it for next production.
numLinha++; // increment line/rule counter.
fseek(entrada, 2, SEEK_CUR);
regras = cria_lista(); // Next lista
```